# Access to fetch at *** from origin *** has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, reactjs, api

I have error

> Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:5000/admin/authenticate' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

My ApiManager

```
function login(username, password) {
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {    
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ username, password })};

    return fetch(`http://localhost:5000/admin/authenticate`, requestOptions)
        .then(handleResponse)
        .then(user => {
            // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
            localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
            return user;
        }
    );
}
```

In Backend Asp.Net Core 2.2 (Startup.cs) I write:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(
        _corsName,
        builder => { builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials(); });}
);
```

Comment: `AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials()` is NOT a valid CORS setup, please take the time to read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSNotSupportingCredentials

Comment: What is the expected result of setting `'Accept': 'application/json'` and `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'` headers at client-side?

Comment: I believe with your code that you only registered the CORS service, and didn't enable it. I'd refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2#enable-cors-with-cors-middleware) and see where your code specifically differs.

Answer (score 9):

i tried anerco's answer but it didn't work for me, i found this [article](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/05/20/aspnet-core-api-allow-cors-requests-from-any-origin-and-with-credentials), it has a very similar solution but with `.SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true)` added and `.AllowAnyOrigin()` removed.

So you should add this code to your Configure method in startup class :

```
app.UseCors(x => x
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true) // allow any origin
                    .AllowCredentials()); // allow credentials
```

I recommend reading the article to get a better understanding of all of this, it's very short and straight to the point.

Answer (score 4):

Hi I'm new on this topic but because I've got this error last week I tried enabling options method and the first part resolved . 
This error happens due to policy and security issues but now I refer you to get the status code and in my case it was 405 error which means now we have to change our headers in the request to allow all methods and origins (no way )
but it doesn't help me out.

So I figured out that I have enabled cookie encryption and session (wide of the point) in my app for my API therefore I disabled them and cleared browser cookie as well .

So try using these:

1. Clear your cookies and add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'` by Mod Header extension and try again to check the fix .
   [mod header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlJHO.png)  - [your header  (client)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsbVp.png)
2. Try using a middle interface to control your request and guide them into the special rules

```
    app.use((req, res, next) => {
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
      next();
    });
```

According to this site : https://medium.com/@dtkatz/3-ways-to-fix-the-cors-error-and-how-access-control-allow-origin-works-d97d55946d9

Answer (score 3):

**FOR NODE EXPRESS GRAPHQL RESTAPI**
*Add this header middleware to avoid CORS and any POST or OPTIONS error*

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
      res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      res.setHeader(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
        "OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE"
      );
      res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization");
      if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
        return res.sendStatus(200);
      }
      next();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
on Startup.cs => Confirgure add:
     app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials());
```

Comment: you can not use .AllowAnyOrigin() and .AllowCredentials() together it throws exception

Answer (score 0):

If your server is express.js based, add these lines to the server:

```js
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
   next();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was trying to make a blob from an image stored on the API (the server) so the URL was pointing to that resource, in that API's `program.cs` class, I already had a CORS policy, but I'd get the exact error as you said. After I read the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0#usecors-and-usestaticfiles-order) (read the first paragraph that you see) about this issue, it is said that if you want to access a resource on the server, by using JavaScript (which is what I was trying to do), then you must call the `app.UseCors();` **BEFORE** the `app.UseStaticFiles();` which is typically the opposite.

My `program.cs`:

```
const string corsPolicyName = "ApiCORS";

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(corsPolicyName, policy =>
    {
        policy.WithOrigins("https://localhost:7212");
    });
});

...

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseSwagger();

app.UseSwaggerUI(settings =>
{
    settings.DisplayRequestDuration();
    settings.EnableTryItOutByDefault();
});

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseCors(corsPolicyName); //  This should be above the UseStaticFiles();

app.UseStaticFiles(); //  Below the UseCors();

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseApiCustomExceptionHandler();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Answer (score -8):

There is a bug in Chrome that has affected users for years now, it can be found [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=67743).

You can use the Chrome extension Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: * found here: `https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi`

Alternatively you can use `http://lacolhost.com/` which points to 127.0.0.1 like localhost.

Comment: This is completely false and misleading. You can use CORS in localhost just fine

Comment: Strange, considering I've used CORS in Chrome on localhost for the last 18 months.

Comment: It is due to a bug found here https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=67743 I guess it doesn't happen to everybody.